# How to get selected simple product Id on checkout_card_add_after observer in magento2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, event-observer, addtocart, associate-products

I want to get selected associated product information from configurable product after an **checkout_cart_add_after** triggered. I'll look after it in mean time,if any helps would be appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below code in your observer file

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

$product = $item->getProduct();
$typeId = $product->getTypeId();
if ($typeId == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {

    $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectedAttributesInfo($product);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply it returns the selected options attribute information and also how do I get the associated product id or other attributes like price.